# In selenium. How do I click the second index/list using Span class?

Tags: python, html, selenium

```
 self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='bog']").click()
```

This is my current code. Using this method. I can click on the first email of my gmail inbox. I want to then click on the second email or the third. But I'm unsure how to do it

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='bog' and @xpath='2']").click()
```

I tried this method but it didn't work.  Using chropath. I was able to search for "bog" and then find out a list of all the emails and each one showed an:

```
"<span id=":2y" class="bog" xpath="1"></span>"
"<span id=":2y" class="bog" xpath="2"></span>"
```

Any help regarding this issue? I would like to able to click on the second email of my inbox every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xpath indexing :

for this xpath :

```
//span[@class='bog']
```

you can have index like below  :

```
(//span[@class='bog'])[1]
```

will represent 1st element. `[2]` will represent 2nd element and `[3]` will represent `3rd` element and so on..

**in code :**

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//span[@class='bog'])[1]").click()
```

or

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//span[@class='bog'])[2]").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this you change the index from [2],[3],[4] it will access the particular element on that particular index

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("((//span[@class='bog'])[2])").click()
```